# What is the best way to hide module method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In JavaScript, it's easy to hide function or variable in closure.
In ruby, private doesn't work for Module method.
Is there best practice to do so?

```
module Lib

  def self.public_function
    private_function
  end

  private # Does not work
  def self.private_function

  end

end

Lib.public_function
```

I've read this post: [Private module methods in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318850/private-module-methods-in-ruby)
But the best answer is not simple enough for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Private module methods in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318850/private-module-methods-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

```
module Lib

  def self.private_function
   puts "k"
  end

  private_class_method(:private_function)

end

Lib.private_function #=> NoMethodError
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve private methods in a module with the macro `private_class_method` like this:

```
def self.private_function
end
private_class_method :private_function
```

Comment: Ruby does not have macros. You mean "method" (or better, "the method [Module#private_class_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method)").

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my language. It does behave like a classic macro, though

Answer (score 2):

`private` only makes the receiver obligatorily implicit, and is not suited for the purpose of hiding a method. `protected` makes the method accessible only within the context of the receiver class, and works better for the purpose of hiding the method.

Comment: Good point, implemented: `Lib.singleton_class.send(:protected, :protected_class_method)`.