# Ruby - Moving rails 'business logic' into service modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to move some rails business logic into a service, following correct OOP protocol. I'm following the method recommended here: [Private module methods in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318850/private-module-methods-in-ruby)

Ultimately, I want to move business logic out of models and controllers into services, which are Plain Old Ruby Objects. So, models will just be concerned with persistence, scoping, & validation.

Is this the correct way to make a service module?

Version 2:

```
module CategorizeJobs

  def self.fetch( location, category_name )
    c = Categorizer.new( location, category_name )
    c.get_jobs
  end

  class Categorizer

    def initialize(location, category_name)
      @location = location
      @category_name = category_name
    end

    def get_jobs
      job_ids = get_correct_jobs
      Category.includes(:jobs).where( jobs: { id:  job_ids } )
    end

    private

      def get_correct_jobs
        jobs = filter_by_location
        jobs = filter_by_category(jobs)

        jobs.collect(&:id)
      end

      def filter_by_category(jobs)
        return jobs unless @category_name.present?

        category = Category.where(name: @category_name).first
        if category
          jobs = jobs.where(category: category)
        end

        jobs
      end

      def filter_by_location
        if @location.present?
          jobs = get_jobs_at_location
        else
          jobs = Job.open
        end
      end

      def get_jobs_at_location(location)
        Job.joins(:location).within(20, origin: @location).open
      end

  end

end
```

Version 1:

```
 module CategorizeJobs

  def self.fetch( location, category_name )
    c = Categorizer.new
    c.perform( location, category_name )
  end


  class Categorizer

    def perform( location, category_name )
      job_ids = get_correct_jobs(location, category_name)
      Category.includes(:jobs).where( jobs: { id:  job_ids } )
    end

    private

      def get_correct_jobs(location, category_name)
        jobs = filter_by_location(location)
        jobs = filter_by_category(jobs, category_name)

        jobs.collect(&:id)
      end

      def filter_by_category(jobs, category_name)
        return jobs unless category_name

        category = Category.where(name: category_name).first
        if category
          jobs = jobs.where(category: category)
        end

        jobs
      end

      def filter_by_location(location)
        if location
          jobs = get_jobs_at_location(location)
        else
          jobs = Job.open
        end
      end

      def get_jobs_at_location(location)
        Job.joins(:location).within(20, origin: location).open
      end

  end

end
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Oops - deleted it by accident! "Is this the correct way to make a service module?"

Comment: You're always passing around location and category name.  Why not create an initializer and store them in variables so you don't need to pass them around?

Comment: Good idea! I moved them into an initialiser.

Answer (score 3):

There is a gem by the name of [Aldous](https://github.com/envato/aldous) that helps you implement service objects based architecture into your Rails applications. Have a look at it.

If you need further help on how to use it and architect your application, you can look at [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/service-objects-with-rails-using-aldous--cms-23689) and [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/one-class-per-rails-controller-action-with-aldous--cms-23714) for more help.

Comment: Thanks! Had a read through - good idea. I don't think I want to completely re-architect my app, I have no idea how this will work with other gems I'm using - and I'll have to train any developers I bring onto the project in Aldous

Comment: @WillTaylor No need to re-architect your app or take the learning curve to implement the gem. Just understand how service objects are implemented through those resources and hack away your project.